# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object How to resolve

Tags: python, string, dataframe, word-cloud

I have doubt. I get error like this :

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

When im trying do wordclous. This is my code below

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
text = df['Tweet_tokenized']
text = df['Tweet_tokenized'].astype(str)
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=480, height=480, margin=0).generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.margins(x=0, y=0)
plt.show()
```

And this is my df:

```
nnamed: 0   clean_tweet Tweet_tokenized polarity    subjectivity
0   0    BOMBSHELL Veteran &amp; business partner ...   ['', 'bombshel', 'veteran', 'amp', 'busi', 'pa...   0.000000    0.000000
1   1   Finally! Suburban women are flocking over to u...   ['final', 'suburban', 'women', 'flock', 'us', ...   0.000000    0.300000
```

How to solve it ?